# pthread returning value from another class

Tags: c++, pthreads

I would like to call a thread (which is declared in a class) from within another class. The function must return a value, but it doesnt work. I'm using POSIX Threads. **If you know of another way please let me know**. **Thanks in advance** - here is the code:

```
//------Class 1 - Declare Thread----------
//------ Header File ------

pthread_t m_thread1;

list<myType*> threadtest();
static void* threadFunction(void *obj);

//------ Source File ------

list<myType*> Class1::threadtest() {
    pthread_create(&m_thread1, NULL, &Class1::threadFunction, this);
    pthread_join(m_thread1, NULL);
}
void* Class1::threadFunction(void *obj) {
    reinterpret_cast<Class1 *> (obj)->threadtest();  //threadtest returns a
                                                     //list<myType*>
    return NULL;
}


//----- Class 2 Source File - Use of thread -------- 
...
mylist = class1object->threadtest();
...
```

**Note:** I succesfully used something similar to the above but the thread function hadn't had to return anything

Comment: If you're waiting on the return value, why run it in another thread?

Comment: I want to speed up the process. Trying different cases, and this function is a little slow to execute. Any suggestions? (But i get your point)

Comment: Running on a different thread and waiting for the thread is not going to speed it up. In fact, it will take longer due to the time required to start the thread. If you want to speed it up, you have to split up your algorithm into pieces and run it on multiple threads.

Comment: So, maybe its not a good tactic to use threads when you are waiting on a return value?

Comment: That would be correct. Unless you are breaking your algorithm into pieces to allow for parallel processing, you won't gain anything by using threads.

Comment: If you actually have work to do while waiting on the other thread, and your compiler supports C++ 11, have a look at [futures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)